# relative path of image gets affected by nested routes in routify

Tags: javascript, relative-path, svelte-3, routify

I have a nested route in routify with the below folder structure, where the image is placed in public folder and referred here and I'm using the image in App.svelte. Everything works fine. when I go to example.com/1/2 the relative path doesn't work properly

```
  public
    --assets
      --images
        --image.png
  src
    --pages
      --[aid]
        --[bid].svelte
      --_layout.svelte
    
    App.svelte
```

App.svelte

```
  <img src="./assets/images/zrx-logo.png" />
```

this is how I referred to the image in App.svelte

ERROR

GET http://localhost:5000/1/assets/images/image.png 404 (Not Found) this is how it gets resolved
instead of http://localhost:5000/assets/images/image.png.

P.S when the URL is example.com/1 the image gets resolved properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an absolute path: `/` (without dot). `./` means the current folder. thus at `http://localhost:5000/1` the current folder is the root of the website which is `public` folder which is translated to `/public`

`./` at `http://localhost:5000/1/2` means `/public/1`

to resolve your issue set the path to `/assets/images/zrx-logo.png` this means we start looking for the file directly from the root folder (`/public`)